# How to use C++ classes in android-ndk project

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

people!
I am looking for an example or any advice, of how to use C++ classes in android-ndk project.
There are a lot of examples, but they all written in pure C. And there are a lot of topics where people asking the same question. But there are stupid answers, or people who answering don't know that C and C++ are different languages )))
I have been searched a lot, I've also been on the 10th search page of google search ), but nothing found )
So, how to use C++ classes in android-ndk project?
Please give an example like famous "hello world".

Problem is when I am including *.h file with
class ndkclass { }; defined into it,
I have got this error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'ndkclass'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your file has .cpp extension? If it has .c extension then compiler thinks your code is C, not C++, and that's why you will get error message.

Using C++ in android-ndk is same as in any other place (Visual C++, XCode, GCC, ...)

Comment: OMG! I read about it, but I thought that class functions implementation should be in c++ file, not c. But there is another thing ))) I must include my header FROM *.cpp file, not *c. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description on how to use opencv c++ classes from android: http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html#android-binary-package-with-ndk
You check the samples as well to see some working examples.